# Eliminate Repeating values in crystal report

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, crystal-reports

I have a problem in printing values on crystal report i want to print allownces of each person in an organization mention in heading row which is repeating in subreport but i have problem while i insert second employee record in payinformation table it repeat the value like in image. so now i want to avoid this but i don't have much experience in crystal reporting so I am in trouble. My table procedure is not i think and join not work proparly. So any of you can suggest me best links of table through i get desired result? Like each person as own allownces and I want to print there values under their names. [Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdx5H.jpg)
I am using visual studio 2012 with crystal reports version CRforVS_13_0_16 and MS sql server 2012.
[my data base tables now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTsPw.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have added first pay data but not able to add second one...

Comment: For this type of report cross tab is the ideal solution and easily you will get the solution..